# **Laravel** form request validation not return errors

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-blade, laravel-5.8

i setup **laravel** 5.8 **form request** with custom message and its validate fine and redirect back to form on invalid input **But** dost error back or i don't look where for errors

**this is my class**

```php
public function create(createUser $request){
    //on invalid input not enter in this class
        //validation
    //dd($request->all('name'));


        $validator = $request->validated();
            if ($validator->fails()) {
                 Session::flash('error', $validator->messages()->first());
                return redirect()->back()->withInput();
            }
```

**request class**

```php
public function rules()
    {

        return [
            'name'      => 'required|max:255'
            ,'email'    => 'string|required|E-mail|unique:users,email'
            ,'birthY'   => 'required|min:4'
            ,'birthM'   => 'required'
            ,'birthD'   => 'required'
            ,'gender'   => 'required'
            ,'Phone'    => 'required|min:11|max:11'
            ,'password' => 'required|min:8'
        ];

    }

    public function messages(){

        return [
            'name.required' => "اسمت چیه ؟!!",
            'email.required' => 'ایمیلت چیه?',
            'gender.required' => 'سرکار خانم یا جناب آقای ؟',
            'Phone.required'    =>'شماره ما توی درباره ما هست  شما بدین شاید باهتون کار داشتیم',
            'birthY.required'  => 'تولدت کیه ؟',
            'birthY.min'  => 'سال ها چهار رقمیه گلم',
            'password.required' =>'رمز بزار تا امن باشی ' ,
            'password.min' =>'حداقل هشتا بزن که کسی شک نکنه ',
            'password.confirmed' =>'هنوز هیچی نشده یادت رفت پسوردت رو  تایید کن تا بفهمم یاد داری',
            'Phone.min' =>  'شمارتو با صفر بزن لطفا'         
        ];
    }
```

and this is my blade where i try to show errors **Not** **Working**!!!!

```php
                @if ($errors->any())
                        &lt;div class="alert alert-danger"&gt;
                            &lt;ul&gt;
                            @foreach ($errors->all() as $error)
                                    &lt;li&gt;{{ $error }} &lt;/li&gt;
                            @endforeach
                            &lt;/ul&gt;
                        &lt;/div&gt;
                @endif


            @isset($messages)
            <?php dd($messages) ?>

            @endisset



        @if (count($errors) > 0)
      <div class="alert alert-danger">
        <?php dd($error) ?>

          <ul>
              @foreach ($errors->all() as $error)

              <li>{{ $error }}</li>

              @endforeach
```

if you need other piece of **code** just let me know   **tnx a lot :)**

Comment: when you use Laravel Form Request Validation (https://laravel.com/docs/master/validation#form-request-validation), Laravel will handle everything for you. You don't have to manually check validation and manually redirect to the previous page. Read the documentation again. Also, use Laravel Telescope for better debugging to make sure you hit the correct end point.

Comment: i know that but i need to know how show my errors messages   that is my main problem

Comment: you said the validation does not trigger. Install Laravel Telescope to debug. Start from scratch with Laravel Form Request Validation Documentation. When you get dd() validation message working, then move on next to display them on your form.

Comment: what the result of  ```dd( $validator)```

Comment: its not get there to get result

Comment: If there are `$errors` you `<?php dd($error) ?>` (you could use `{{ dd($error) }}` in blade). Where does `$error` come from?

Answer (score 26, accepted):

If this happens to you with postman remember to check that the header accepts json.

Accept: application/json
Content-Type: application/json

Comment: Great you saved my day!

Comment: Nice, no problem guy!

Comment: i actually new another project and paste entire all my classes and migrations and its worked but its sounds like its  work for a that dude above so thank you for collaboration